# I have added admin interface to my app , but under django login interface I am not able to see my created app

Tags: python, django

```
**Below are mentioned files under**
```

In the admin interface - is it possible to set a field to readonly, but also set the value? For example, I am building a CRM and a organization will have a program. I want the user who is creating a program to always use the organization that they belong to.

example:

Program name helloapp

User name helloapp

I mentioned it as
 admin.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Msisdn

admin.site.register(Msisdn)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'helloapp',

)
```

created simple form to add numbers along with creation date and other fields

models.py

```
class Msisdn(models.Model):
    msisdn=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_by=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    created_on=models.DateTimeField()
    updated_by=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    updated_on=models.DateTimeField()
    status=models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' %self.msisdn
```

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS` should be in `settings.py`, not in `admin.py`

Comment: ITS UNDER settings.py only